# c# Datagridview substring filter

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter

I want to filter a bounded DataGridView with substring Date field. I have a filled datagridview with a date column `BeginDate` in format `yyyy/mm/dd`; how can I filter it to get say all 2013 rows?

```
((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("string.substring(BeginDate,1,4)=2013";
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: @mjwills  Sorry for delay, nothing happened, i think it takes that as a string.

Comment: What about `((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "BeginDate >= #1/1/2013# AND BeginDate <#1/1/2014#"`?